# django template to get number from alphanumeric

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

In Django template, how can I get last 3 digits from a alphanumeric word, ***without*** using custom django filter.

Eg: input will always be in this format: "Foo-bar123"

output required: "123"

I couldn't find any built-ins that could achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) filter.

```
{{ myvalue|slice:"-3:" }}
```

Comment: doh! Thank you.
Small correction - it will be |slice